# Android automatically makes a call after connecting to audio bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth

After connecting to my bluetooth headphone, my phone automatically calls my friend(let's call him Bob), when i reject the call it calls again, this issue only happens with my new bluetooth speaker, my device doesn't have this issue with any other audio or bluetooth devices.

P. S:Android version:8:0:0
Emui version:8:0:0:0

Comment: Does the Bluetooth headphone have buttons/functions to accept a call/turn volume/etc.? Have you tested on other phones? Might be a defect on the headphone.

Comment: @Andrew T., the bluetooth headphone doesn't have any buttons/functions, i have tested it on several devices, on windows 10 it automatically changes volume to 100 after connecting, on some android devices it makes a call, in some other android devices it makes a call and automatically plays a song.

Comment: Is there a way to reprogram the headphone or any option to prevent the bluetooth headphone from making call, playing music, changing volume?

Comment: There might be a way... I've done a quick research and came with [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/alea31/disabling_headphone_controls/) that mentions [Button Mapper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flar2.homebutton) app. I haven't tried it, and you probably need to do a trial & error on determining which keys are pressed and need to be disabled...

Comment: Actually the app doesn't work very well, it doesn't detect call button, also sometimes it doesn't bypass the button function.